# Magento2 soap/rest api for third-party consumer

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, soap, oauth

I'm trying to create a **webservice client** for **Magento2 api**. I would like to know whether Magento2 supports oauth2 or oauth1.0. Could someone clarify if Magento2 SOAP API also requires oauth process?

Answer (score 2):

1. They are using 1.0 ([from the dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html)):

> Magento OAuth authentication is based on OAuth 1.0a, an open standard
>   for secure API authentication. OAuth is a token-passing mechanism that
>   allows a system to control which external applications have access to
>   internal data without revealing or storing any user IDs or passwords.
>
> In Magento, a third-party extension that uses OAuth for authentication
>   is called an integration. An integration defines which resources the
>   extension can access. The extension can be granted access to all
>   resources or a customized subset of resources.
>
> As the process of registering the integration proceeds, Magento
>   creates the tokens that the extension needs for authentication. It
>   first creates a request token. This token is short-lived and must be
>   exchanged for access token. Access tokens are long-lived and will not
>   expire unless the merchant revokes access to the extension.

2. Yes it require OAuth process.